# Tangent space at a point in invertible upper triangular matrices

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

> Let $p\in M$ with $M$ being the group of invertible upper triangular matrices. Determine $T_pM$.

My idea - I know that $M$ is a submanifold of the vector space $U_n$ (upper triangular matrices). Moreover, it is an open subset of it. By a theorem, for every $p\in U_n$, $T_pU_n=U_n$. Now I vaguely remember a theorem that says that if $U\subset M$ is open then for every $x\in U$, $T_xM=T_xU$ (but I wasn't able to prove it). So my feeling is that for our $M$, $T_pM=U_n$.

Is my idea correct? If so, can anyone provide me a proof of the theorem I stated?

The definition of tangent space Im working with is $T_xM=\{[\gamma]_x:\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M, \gamma(0)=x\}$ with $\gamma\sim\delta$ if for every chart $f$ that contains $x$, $(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=(f\circ\delta)'(0)$.

For embedded submanifold, a chart $\phi$ and $y=\phi(x)$, $T_xM=ImD\phi_y$.

Comment: be inspired by the first exercise in this document : https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/pavel.tumarkin/past/spring16/RG/RG11-sols.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tangent spaces are essentially derivations, so they are local. From your geometric definition of tangent spaces, we can define an isomorphism between $T_x U$ and $T_x M$, by sending $[\gamma]$ to $[\gamma]$. It has an inverse, which is sending $[\gamma]$ to $[\gamma|_U]$. You can show they are both well-defined.

Comment: I tried defining this map, but couldn't show that it is well defined (how to go from charts of U and M, and essentialy what does $\gamma\mid_U$ mean? $U$ is in the range not the domain

Comment: I mean the image. Think geometrically. Since U is a neighborhood of x and $\gamma$ is smooth, we can always find an $a>0 $, such that the image of $\gamma|_{(-a,a)}$   is contained in $U$.

Comment: And charts of $U$ are also charts of $M$. Charts of $M $ intersecting $U$ become charts of $U$. And in fact, the definition I learned is that for any function $f$ on $M$, $(f\circ \gamma)^{'}(0)=(f\circ \delta)^{'}(0)$. If you have a chart $(\phi,x)$, then $T_p M=\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_{p} \}$